# Javascript slider counter triggers one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning JS/JQuery by making a slider. 
The problem is that my counter which should each time increment by -980px, stays only at -980px. i assume it happens because it gets triggered only one time. Whats is the problem, why it only reaches -980px ?

```
<div id="wrapper" class="group">
    <div id="slider">
        <ul id="slide_effect" class="group" style="height: 337px; width: 3920px;">
            <li class="slides" name="slide1">
                <img src="img/easiest_way_to.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li class="slides" name="slide2">
                <img src="img/enterprise_solutions.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li class="slides " name="slide3">
                <img src="img/find_out_how.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li class="slides" name="slide1">
                <img src="img/transactional-email-service-2.jpg" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button id="leftBtn">Back</button>
</div>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var backBtn = $('#leftBtn');
    backBtn.on('click', function () {
        var slideEffect = $('#slide_effect');
        function setWidth() {
            var width = 0;
            function calcWidth() {
                width -= 980;
                return width;
            }
            return calcWidth;
        }
        var bannerWidth = setWidth();
        var translate = "translate3d(" + bannerWidth() + "px, 0,0)";
        slideEffect.css({
            'transform': translate
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: inside `setWidth()` function you set `width` to 0 so you always get -980

Comment: Its outside of calcWidth function, so it doesn`t reset it to 0; its called closure function

Comment: but you call `setWidth()` so `calcWidth()` no matter what get width = 0